# Printing Permutations

Tags: java, beginner, array, recursion

Following is a leetcode problem:
Given an array nums of distinct integers, return all the possible permutations. You can return all the possible permutations. You can return the answer in any order.

Following is the code written by me for the above problem. It gives the correct output:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void printPerm(int[] arr, int[] perm, int n){
        if(arr.length == 0){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(perm));
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            int num = arr[i];
            int[] newArr = new int[arr.length-1];
            for(int j=0, k=0; j<arr.length; j++){
                if(j != i){
                    newArr[k] = arr[j];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            if(arr.length == n){
                perm[0] = num;
            }
            else {
                int[] tempArr = new int[n];
                for(int j=0; j<perm.length; j++){
                    tempArr[j] = perm[j];
                }
                tempArr[n - arr.length] = num;
                for(int j=0; j<tempArr.length; j++){
                    perm[j] = tempArr[j];
                }
            }
            printPerm(newArr, perm, n);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {1,2,3};
        int n = arr.length;
        int[] perm = new int[n];
        printPerm(arr, perm, n);
    }
}
```

I haven't done advanced topics such as linked list or Arraylist. So according to that what suggestions you have for any improvement that can be made? I'll be glad to have your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't done advanced topics such as linked list or Arraylist.

That's OK, we won't need them here.

This recursive algorithm, based on picking every number from the array, and then recursively generating all the permutations of the remaining items, is a perfectly reasonable algorithm for this task. There are different options, but this is fine.

However, it is implemented with a lot of heavy-duty array manipulation. That costs a lot of code, and possibly time, if this was ever used to enumerate sufficiently large permutations. You can use a very similar algorithm (maybe even the same algorithm, depending on how you look at it) without allocating any extra arrays, by using some implementation tricks.

The key idea is, rather than using two separate arrays, logically dividing the one existing array into two different areas: the "fixed" area, where the elements won't be changed deeper in the recursion (this corresponds to `perm`), and the remaining area, which is where elements are "picked" out from (this corresponds to `arr`). Initially the fixed area has a length of zero, every step down the recursion fixes one more element, when the entire array is fixed then a permutation has been generated. After returning from one level of recursion to the previous level, one element is "unfixed", and restored to its old location in the remaining area.

It may initially seem as if appending an arbitrary chosen element to the "fixed" area requires moving a lot of elements in the array, but that is not necessary: we can swap whatever element is "in the way" with the chosen element (that changes the order of the elements that remain to be picked deeper in the recursion, but that's fine, it just changes the order in which permutations are generated, which was allowed for this problem). Restoring that element back to its old location (after the recursive call returns) can be done by performing the same swap again.

Some minor optimizations could be done (the swaps do some redundant writes when viewed in the context of occurring in a loop that repeatedly swaps the same first element with different second elements, swapping an element with itself can be avoided by peeling the first iteration off of the loop, maybe more), but I'll leave them for another time. The main point that I wanted to make with this review is not how it could be done the most efficient way, but rather than adding a simple-but-powerful trick to the same basic algorithm can save you a lot of heavy array manipulations.

The code ends up a lot simpler: (this code shows strong similarities to some existing solutions that you may find on the internet)

```
public static void printPerm(int[] arr, int fixed) {
    if (fixed == arr.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = fixed; i < arr.length; i++){
        swap(arr, fixed, i);
        printPerm(arr, fixed + 1);
        swap(arr, fixed, i);
    }
}

static void swap(int[] array, int a, int b) {
    int t = array[a];
    array[a] = array[b];
    array[b] = t;
}
```